# How to bind an event listener to JavaFX TextFields in a dialog box. When the fields are empty, the OK button becomes disabled and vice versa

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, dialog, event-handling

Here is the code that supports what i'm trying to accomplish:

Dialog Controller Code:

```
public class DialogController {
@FXML private TextField firstName;
@FXML private TextField lastName;
@FXML private TextField phoneNumber;
@FXML private TextField notes;
@FXML private DialogPane dialogPane;

//All getters defined here

public void keyReleasedHandler(){
    Boolean firstNameEmpty = (firstName.getText().isEmpty() || firstName.getText().trim().isEmpty());
    Boolean lastNameEmpty = (lastName.getText().isEmpty() || lastName.getText().trim().isEmpty());
    Boolean phoneNumberEmpty = (phoneNumber.getText().isEmpty() || phoneNumber.getText().trim().isEmpty());
    if (firstNameEmpty || lastNameEmpty || phoneNumberEmpty){
        //When the dialog box opens and I type or a delete a letter from any of the event binded fields, a null pointer exception is thrown
        dialogPane.lookupButton(ButtonType.OK).setDisable(true);
    }
    dialogPane.lookupButton(ButtonType.OK).setDisable(false);
}

public Contact processResults(){
    String firstName = getFirstName().getText().trim();
    String lastName = getLastName().getText().trim();
    String phoneNumber = getPhoneNumber().getText().trim();
    String notes = getNotes().getText().trim();

    return new Contact(phoneNumber, firstName, lastName, notes);
}}
```

Relevant Method and UI definitions from my Main Controller:

```
public class Controller {
@FXML private TableView<Contact> tableView;
@FXML private BorderPane mainBorderPane;

public void handleNewContact(){
    Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.initOwner(mainBorderPane.getScene().getWindow());
    dialog.setTitle("Add a new contact to your list");
    dialog.setHeaderText("Use this dialog to create a new contact");
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("dialogWindow.fxml"));
    try {
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(loader.load());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't load the dialog");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);

    Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();

    if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
        DialogController controller = loader.getController();
        Contact contact = controller.processResults();
        contactData.addContact(contact);
        tableView.getSelectionModel().select(contact);
    }
}
```

My thinking process behind the keyReleasedHandler() is that would function as validation for my TextFields within my 'New Contact Dialog'. In my main controller, I handled the creation of the dialog's UI via its FXML and manually added ButtonTypes OK and Cancel in code. I tied all of the dialog TextFields onKeyReleased to my keyReleasedHandler(). Whenever I type anything in my 'validated' fields, a null pointer exception is thrown (i'm assuming that the dialogPane lookup method is returning null somehow).

Alternative implementations for this validation feature would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing looks like a Swing implementation. A lot of stuff can be done with binding.

Whatever you are doing in `keyReleasedHandler()`, you can replace with this:

```
dialogPane.lookupButton(ButtonType.OK).disableProperty()
    .bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
        () -> firstName.getText().trim().isEmpty() ||
              lastName.getText().trim().isEmpty() ||
              phoneNumber.getText().trim().isEmpty(),
        firstName.textProperty(),
        lastName.textProperty(),
        phoneNumber.textProperty()
    ));
```

This will cause the button to be disabled when any of the 3 `TextField` has empty text.

Some side notes (not really related to the answer):

- `getText().isEmpty()` isn't really needed since you have `getText().trim().isEmpty()`, though it *can* be arguably faster to include that.
- In your question, you used `Boolean` to store a boolean value. It is definitely better to use the primitive `boolean` type.

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying to my question. I implemented the code that you supplied in my keyReleasedHandler() and it is still throwing a null pointer exception. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: @JustinHernandez You need to tell us where (in code) that it happens. Also note that you should really remove your key events now that you are using binding.

Comment: @JustinHernandez The code in this answer is supposed to *replace* the `keyReleasedHandler`. You just need this binding, you don't need the handler at all. (Apart from this being cleaner, your approach doesn't even try to handle the case of the user pasting text with the mouse.)

Comment: @JustinHernandez The null pointer exception is likely happening because you add the buttons to the dialog in the main controller, so those are not added until after the dialog controller's `initialize()` method is called. Is there a reason for this? It would seem more natural to add those buttons in the dialog controller.

Comment: Thank you James_D and Jai. Jai's code works perfectly and James that was exactly what was going on. The code for adding the ButtonTypes should definitely be in the DialogController's initialize(). Can either of you explain the significance of using the .textProperty() for the UI in the binding and briefly how the binding works?

Comment: @JustinHernandez See [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107). A binding just registers the required listener(s) to ensure one property always contains the same value as another observable value.

Comment: @JustinHernandez Properties and binding aren't topics that can be explained in a sentence or two. The tutorial link that James_D gave is definitely a good place to start. It is definitely a good investment to spend time understanding about these two because they are some of the most important/useful features that JavaFX has over older API like Swing.